# Use single instance of class across many classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

On an Net.Core 6 project I have the `IEndpoint` extension

```
public interface IEndpoint {
  void Map(IEndpointRouteBuilder builder);  
}
```

And an implementation example:

```
public class CountryEndpoint : IEndpoint {
  
  public void Map(IEndpointRouteBuilder builder) {

    builder.MapGet("countries", async ([FromServices] IService service) => {
      List<Country> countries = await service.GetCountries();
      return Results.Ok(countries);
    })
    .WithName("Countries");
    .WithApiVersionSet(versionSet)
    .MapToApiVersion( 1.0 );

  }

}
```

I configure the endpoints on my application using:

```
builder.Services.AddEndpoints(typeof(Program));

WebApplication application = builder.Build();

application.MapEndpoints();
```

Where `AddEndpoints` and `MapEndpoints` extensions are:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddEndpoints(this IServiceCollection services, params Type[] types) {

  services
    .Scan(x => x.FromAssembliesOf(types).AddClasses(y => y.AssignableTo(typeof(IEndpoint))).AsImplementedInterfaces().WithScopedLifetime());

  return services;

}

public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions {

  public static IEndpointRouteBuilder MapEndpoints(this IEndpointRouteBuilder builder) {

    using (IServiceScope scope = builder.ServiceProvider.CreateScope()) {
      IEnumerable<IEndpoint> endpoints = scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<IEndpoint>();

      foreach (IEndpoint endpoint in endpoints)
        endpoint.Map(builder);
    }

    return builder;

  }

}
```

**Question**

On `CountryEndpoint's` Map` method I have:

```
.WithApiVersionSet(versionSet)
```

The `versionSet` variable is created in `Program` code as follows:

```
ApiVersionSet versionSet = application.NewApiVersionSet().HasApiVersion(new ApiVersion(1.0)).ReportApiVersions().Build();
```

How can I create such a variable and use it in Endpoints' `Map` method?

Usually the `versionSet` variable and the `Map` methods are in `Program` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create static class with corresponding static field (for example a partial `Program` class) and use it to store the value and use it in `Map`:

Top-level statement (`Program.cs`):

```cs
...
ApiVersionSet versionSet = application.NewApiVersionSet().HasApiVersion(new ApiVersion(1.0)).ReportApiVersions().Build();
VersionSet  = versionSet;
application.MapEndpoints(); // use Program.VersionSet in IEndpoint.Map implementation
...

// end of top-level statement
static partial class Program
{
    internal static ApiVersionSet VersionSet {get;set;}
}
```

But I would argue that making `ApiVersionSet` a parameter of `IEndpoint.Map` and `ApplicationBuilderExtensions.MapEndpoints` would be a much better approach:

```cs
public interface IEndpoint {
  void Map(IEndpointRouteBuilder builder, ApiVersionSet versionSet);  
}

public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions {
  public static IEndpointRouteBuilder MapEndpoints(this IEndpointRouteBuilder builder, ApiVersionSet versionSet) {

    using (IServiceScope scope = builder.ServiceProvider.CreateScope()) {
      IEnumerable<IEndpoint> endpoints = scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<IEndpoint>();

      foreach (IEndpoint endpoint in endpoints)
        endpoint.Map(builder, versionSet); // pass it here
    }

    return builder;
  }
}
```

And in top-level statement:

```cs
ApiVersionSet versionSet = ...;
application.MapEndpoints(versionSet);
```